# Using .bib file with lncs format but references not appearing in pdf

Tags: bibtex, lncs

I have a LaTeX file in `lncs` format named say `paper.latex`.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
...
\begin{document}
....

\bibliography{paper}
\end{document}
```

I have a separate `paper.bib` file.

But `references` not working.

But if I change it to

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
...
\end{thebibliography}
```

in place of `\bibliography{paper}` giving references in `.tex` file itself, there is no problem.

Why this happens and how can I move forward with `.bib` file?

Comment: Have you run `bibtex` to generate the references and then run latex again to include them?

Comment: Yes, done it. My .bbl file is empty.

Comment: In that case you need to give more of a hint as to what your code looks like, preferably a complete small document and bib file that reproduces the problem, a row of dots doesn't give many clues. Do you have any `\cite` commands in your document? the bbl will be empty if you do not (if ypu provided an example, wouldn't need to ask...)

Answer (score 1):

If you have no `\cite` commands in your tex file then you have nothing to include into the references. If you just want to include all references without actually referring them, use `\nocite{*}`

Comment: I have added a test \cite command added but ? displayed inside []

Comment: @jim you need to run `latex`, then `bibtex`, then `latex` again twice. See wikibooks: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Why_won.27t_LaTeX_generate_any_output.3F. Replace `latex` with whatever compiler you use

Comment: @jim here is an excellent answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number